# Unity some noise in audio after convert Byte[] to AudioClip

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, audioclip

I'm trying to convert a base64 into a byte[] and in a audioClip but i'm getting some noise in my sound.

I'm using this class to convert byte[] to AudioClip.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace WWUtils.Audio{

  public class WAV  {
     // properties

     public float[] LeftChannel { get; internal set; }
     public float[] RightChannel { get; internal set; }
     public int ChannelCount { get; internal set; }
     public int SampleCount { get; internal set; }
     public int Frequency { get; internal set; }

     // convert two bytes to one float in the range -1 to 1

  static float bytesToFloat(byte firstByte, byte secondByte) {
      // convert two bytes to one short (little endian)
      short s = (short)((secondByte << 8) | firstByte);
      // convert to range from -1 to (just below) 1
      return s / 32768.0F;
  }

  static int bytesToInt(byte[] bytes,int offset=0){
      int value=0;
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
          value |= ((int)bytes[offset+i])<<(i*8);
      }
      return value;
  }

  private static byte[] GetBytes(string filename){
      return File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
  }

  // Returns left and right double arrays. 'right' will be null if sound is mono.
  public WAV(string filename):
      this(GetBytes(filename)) {}

  public WAV(byte[] wav){

      // Determine if mono or stereo
      ChannelCount = wav[22];     // Forget byte 23 as 99.999% of WAVs are 1 or 2 channels

      // Get the frequency
      Frequency = bytesToInt(wav,24);

      // Get past all the other sub chunks to get to the data subchunk:
      int pos = 12;   // First Subchunk ID from 12 to 16

      // Keep iterating until we find the data chunk (i.e. 64 61 74 61 ...... (i.e. 100 97 116 97 in decimal))
      while(!(wav[pos]==100 && wav[pos+1]==97 && wav[pos+2]==116 && wav[pos+3]==97)) {
          pos += 4;
          int chunkSize = wav[pos] + wav[pos + 1] * 256 + wav[pos + 2] * 65536 + wav[pos + 3] * 16777216;
          pos += 4 + chunkSize;
      }
      pos += 8;

      // Pos is now positioned to start of actual sound data.
      SampleCount = (wav.Length - pos)/2;     // 2 bytes per sample (16 bit sound mono)
      if (ChannelCount == 2) SampleCount /= 2;        // 4 bytes per sample (16 bit stereo)

      // Allocate memory (right will be null if only mono sound)
      LeftChannel = new float[SampleCount];
      if (ChannelCount == 2) RightChannel = new float[SampleCount];
      else RightChannel = null;

      // Write to double array/s:
      int i=0;
      while (pos < wav.Length) {
          LeftChannel[i] = bytesToFloat(wav[pos], wav[pos + 1]);
          pos += 2;
          if (ChannelCount == 2) {
              RightChannel[i] = bytesToFloat(wav[pos], wav[pos + 1]);
              pos += 2;
          }
          i++;
      }
  }
 public override string ToString (){
      return string.Format ("[WAV: LeftChannel={0}, RightChannel={1}, ChannelCount={2}, SampleCount={3}, Frequency={4}]", LeftChannel, RightChannel, ChannelCount, SampleCount, Frequency);
  }
```

}

}

And this to play audioClip

```
  var recByte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
     WAV wav = new WAV(recByte);
     AudioClip audioClip = AudioClip.Create("soundLenny-Result", 
wav.SampleCount, 1, wav.Frequency, false, false);
     audioClip.SetData(wav.LeftChannel, 0);
//PlayClip...
```

I'm trying to convert one of the following types. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#audio-outputs

with this riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm i get some noise on audio.
i'm tryng to convert this format riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm.

If i use riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm i get a IndexOutOfRangeException, if a use riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm audio is noise

This is the error.

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. WWUtils.Audio.WAV..ctor (System.Byte[] wav) (at Assets/Scripts/WAV.cs:68)

If i make this with an microphone recorded wav file the script works fine. How can i correct this?

Comment: I'm not clear on the issue. Is your program completing, but the audio is noisy? Or is your program halting with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`? Seems like it has to be one or the other, unless you can explain.

Comment: sorry, if i use riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm i get a IndexOutOfRangeException, if a use riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm audio is noise. I will edit the post.

Comment: The noisy one is probably the right one. The noise could be due to math or rounding errors. I believe you are losing the high bit when you convert to `short`, which is a 15-bit signed value. Try using `ushort` or `int`. (FYI the framework is optimized for `int`, so it may actually perform better).